# Creating a plugin for adding and editing attribute data through a GUI

Tags: qgis-plugins, point, attribute-table, gui

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a plugin using python that uses a GUI to edit attribute data instead of the normal attribute table. I want to make a plugin that makes it easier for the less computerly abled to add point data to an already existing point layer, input basic information about that point (preferably through roll-down choices etc.) and then edit the point afterwards.

I'm completely new to python as well as QGIS but I want to try do as much as possible myself, but I'm not sure if QGIS allows for adding your own GUI etc.

What is possible and what is not?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @JWes! Indeed it is possible! Here are a couple of posts describing how to design a plugin for different purposes: [http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html); and [http://www.digital-geography.com/build-qgis-plugin/](http://www.digital-geography.com/build-qgis-plugin/). I suggest building the structure of a plugin using the **Plugin  Builder** as mentioned in the posts and get comfortable using Qt Designer for the GUI. **Everything you mentioned is possible** :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll follow the guides and see if I can make it work! :)

Comment: You don't need a plugin to edit attributes. QGIS provide several ways to define the GUI for attributes editor dialog: 1. Autogenerate, 2. D-n-D designer, 3. ui-file. Also you can setup different controls for editing fields. See layer properties dialog, fields tab.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was after, although i want to bind a specific icon on the toolbar to load the layer file, making it editable and thereafter adding a point.